# Matching template aliases as template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, template-aliases

I'm currently writting a metafunction to evaluate expressions, something like boost::mpl::apply:

```
template<typename EXPRESSION , typename... ARGS>
using eval = typename eval_impl<EXPRESSION,ARGS...>::result;
```

As you can see, I'm using C++11 template aliases to avoid writting `typename ::result` when using the evaluator.

Among other specializations, `eval_impl` (The implementation of the evaluation metafunction) has an specializationfor the case the user passes a parametrized expression (Such as a metafunction) and a set of parameters. In other words, for using `eval` as a high-order metafunction to evaluate a metafunction with a set of specified parameters.

For that case, I have written a specialization as follows:

```
template<template<typename...> class F , typename... PLACEHOLDERS , typename... ARGS>
struct eval_impl<F<PLACEHOLDERS...>,ARGS...> : public F<ARGS...> {}
```

Now consider a use case:

```
template<typename ARG , typename... ARGS> using first_of = ARG;

using call = eval<first_of<_1,_2,_3,_4> , bool,float,char,int>;
```

Here we define a custom metafunction  `first_of` as a template alias, and we pass it to `eval` together with a set of parameters to be called (evaluated) with. `_1`, `_2`... are just placeholders.

I have expected that `eval` call instances the specialization defined above, but it doesn't.
And if the aliased type is not a type itself, but a one-parameter template, GCC 4.8.1 says:

> Error: Expected one template parameter, two provided

At the point of instantation of that `eval_impl` specialization.

So that errors give me to think that **the template alias is not taken in the template template parameter of the partial specialization, the aliased type is matched instead.**

As you can see in the examples, thats not what I wan't, I need the template alias to be matched as any other metafunction. **Is there any way to achieve that?**

Comment: A specialization of an alias-template *is equivalent* to the aliased type; also "An alias template name is never deduced." [temp.alias]/2

Comment: You can pass the template-arguments (as a `std::tuple`) and the metafunction separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *this* close! You only need to use a class instead of an alias:

```
template<typename ARG, typename... ARGS>
struct first_of { using type = ARG; };
```

See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72c3e694db6c75ec).

You cannot use an alias directly because

```
 first_of<_1,_2,_3,_4>
```

is *immediately* substituted for `_1`, which is not of the form expected by `eval_impl`.

I don't find this is a limitation because we usually define template functions in the above form, and *then* define additional aliases like

```
template<typename ARG, typename... ARGS>
using first_of_t = typename first_of<ARG, ARGS...>::type;
```

for easier use. So we usually have both; you'll have to use the former with `eval`.

---

**Attempt 2.** Also note that direct use of an alias is possible without placeholders at all:

```
template<template<typename...> class F, typename... ARGS>
using alias_eval = F<ARGS...>;
```

in which case you can say

```
using alias_call = alias_eval<first_of_t, bool, float, char, int>;
```

as in your first attempt. See [updated example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/091d7e49cf2cf080). But I guess this is of no use because you intend to use placeholders in a less trivial way.

---

**Attempt 3.** Yet another option is to *delay* substitution of the alias, e.g.

```
template<template<typename...> class F, typename... PLACEHOLDERS>
struct holder {};

template<typename EXPRESSION, typename... ARGS>
struct holder_eval_impl;

template<template<typename...> class F, typename... PLACEHOLDERS, typename... ARGS>
struct holder_eval_impl<holder<F, PLACEHOLDERS...>, ARGS...> :
    public F<ARGS...> {};

template<typename EXPRESSION, typename... ARGS>
using holder_eval = typename holder_eval_impl<EXPRESSION, ARGS...>::type;
```

which is very close to your intended syntax

```
using holder_call =
    holder_eval<holder<first_of,_1,_2,_3,_4>, bool, float, char, int>;
```

especially if you use a short name for `holder`. Again, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04bf0cfa8bc9891f).