# Partial template-template based specialization vs explicit partial template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, template-meta-programming

Given a template, for example `foo`:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
struct foo {};
```

And two partial specializations for a template `bar`:

```
template<template<typename...> class T , typename... ARGS>
struct bar<T<ARGS...>>
{};

template<typename... ARGS>
struct bar<foo<ARGS...>>
{};
```

**Is not the second partial specialization more specialized than the first and must be instanced instead of the template-template parameter specialization?**

### Some context:

I'm currently writting multiple-variable lambda expressions for template meta-programming based on [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106611100185X).

As the paper shows, one could develop easily tmp lambda expressions given a Haskell-like `let` expression. In my case, I have extended the contents of the paper developing variadic-templates based multiple variable let expressions (Via curryfying multiple nested unary let expressions), and then implementing multiple-variable lambda expressions.

My lambda expression template, `tml::multi_lambda`, is defined as follows:

```
template<typename BODY , typename... VARIABLES>
struct multi_lambda
{
    template<typename... ARGS>
    using result = tml::eval<tml::multi_let<VARIABLES...,
                                            ARGS...,
                                            BODY
                                           >>;
};
```

where `tml::eval` is a metafunction for evaluating expressions, like Boost::mpl `mpl::apply` (See [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923628/matching-template-aliases-as-template-template-parameters) for more context).

The evaluation function `tml::eval` is specialized both for generic functional expressions, and specifically for this lambda expressions. That are the two specializations of the above example.

When I try to evaluate a lambda expressions, like:

```
using lambda = tml::multi_lambda<_1,_2, f<_1,_2>>; //f is a function, 
                                                   //_1 _2 are placeholders
using result = tml::eval<lambda,int,int>; //Evaluate lambda with int int as parameters
```

`tml::eval` instantiates the generic template-template specialization (Designed for generic evaluable expressions) instead of the partial specialization for lambdas.

### EDIT: Implementation of `tml::eval` and SSCCE

`tml::eval` is a metafunction dessigned to evaluate any kind of expression, returning the result. The default implementation is specialized for three cases:

1. **The expression is not a function, is a value only**: The result of evaluating such expression is the expression itself:

   ```
   template<typename E>
   struct evaluate_impl<E>
   {
       using result = E;
   };
   ```
2. **The expression is a function**: The result of the evaluation is the value of the `result` member type of the function. The parameters of the function are evaluated too (To take care of nested expressions):

   ```
   template<template<typename...> class F , typename... ARGS>
   struct evaluate_impl<F<ARGS...>> : public F<tml::eval<ARGS>...>
   {};
   ```
3. **The expression is a function, and more argumments are passed to `tml::eval` to evaluate the expression with that custom argumments**: The parameters of the expression are ignored and the custom are passed and evaluated:

   ```
   template<template<typename...> class F , typename... PLACEHOLDERS , typename... ARGS>
   struct evaluate_impl<F<PLACEHOLDERS...>,ARGS...> : public F<tml::eval<ARGS>...>
   {};
   ```

So `tml::eval` is just a template alias to ride over the `typename ::result`:

```
template<typename... ARGS>
using eval = typename eval_impl<ARGS...>::result;
```

Finally, the user could specialize `eval_impl` to override that default behaviour, or make corner cases work. For example, my one-variable lambda expressions template, defined as follows:

```
template<typename VARIABLE , typename VALUE , typename BODY>
struct lambda
{
    template<typename ARG>
    using result = tml::eval<tml::let<VARIABLE , ARG , BODY>>;
};
```

specializes `eval_impl` to make evaluation of lambda expressions work:

```
template<typename VARIABLE , typename BODY , typename ARG>
struct evaluate_impl<tml::lambda<VARIABLE,BODY>,ARG>
{
    using result = typename tml::lambda<VARIABLE,BODY>::template result<ARG>;
};
```

The multiple-variable lambda expressions which I have the problem take a similar approach:

```
template<typename... VARIABLES , typename BODY , typename... ARG>
struct evaluate_impl<tml::multi_lambda<BODY,VARIABLES...>,ARGS...>
{
    using result = typename tml::multi_lambda<BODY,VARIABLES...>::template result<ARGS...>;
};
```

But instead of working (Like the one variable counterpart), `tml::eval` instantiates the case three of the default `evaluate_impl` implementation, or fails due to ambiguous specializations (Case three vs `multi_lambda` specialization).

Here is an SSCCE:

```
//An example function:
template<typename... ARGS>
struct F
{
    using result = std::integral_constant<std::size_t,sizeof...(ARGS)>;
};


//This works fine:

using lambda_1 = tml::lambda<_1,F<_1,_1,_1,_1>>;
using result_1 = tml::eval<lambda_1,int>; //Call the lambda with int as parameter


//This doesn't work:

using lambda_2 = tml::multi_lambda<_1,_2,F<_1,_1,_2,_2>>;
using result_2 = tml::eval<lambda_2,int,int>; //Call the lambda with two int as parameters.
```

The evaluation of `lambda_2` fails with:

`functional.hpp:167:76: error: ambiguous class template instantiation for 'struct tml::impl::evaluate_impl<tml::impl::multi_lambda<tml::placeholders::_1, tml::placeholders::_2, f<tml::placeholders::_1, tml::placeholders::_1, tml::placeholders::_2, tml::placeholders::_2> >, int, int>'
     using eval = typename impl::evaluate_impl<EXPRESSION , ARGS...>::result;
                                                                            ^
functional.hpp:116:16: error: candidates are: struct tml::impl::evaluate_impl<F<PLACEHOLDERS ...>, ARG, ARGS ...>
         struct evaluate_impl<F<PLACEHOLDERS...> , ARG , ARGS...> : 
                ^
In file included from main.cpp:24:0:
lambda.hpp:160:16: error:                 struct tml::impl::evaluate_impl<tml::impl::multi_lambda<BODY, VARIABLES ...>, ARGS ...>
         struct evaluate_impl<multi_lambda<BODY,VARIABLES...>,ARGS...> :`

I'm using GCC4.8.2

Comment: @DieterLücking writting an explicit name instead of that examples?

Comment: Do you mean "Is not the first partial specialization more explicit than the second..." ?

Comment: @Danvil thanks for the advise. I mean the second (The `foo` one) over the first (The generic template-template parameter `T` one).

Comment: `lambda` does not look like a template template to me, so why should the first specialization be used?

Comment: I tried [this SSCCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a1f4e8c3e7389e6), but it seems to work. Could you please provide an SSCCE which actually shows your problem?

Comment: @DanielFrey Ah, you beat my by mere seconds ;) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3607596b68ead0b6

Comment: The template template version (the first) is more specialized, and will be preferred over the one using `template<typename... ARGS>` (the second).

Comment: @Danvil why do you think that exactly?

Comment: So a first pass reading is that the more specialized one should be used, and that the general rule for "more specialized" is `A<>` is more specialized than `B<>` if every `B<>` can match `A<>`, while not every `A<>` can match `B<>`.  This may not be how the low level details work, but it seems to imply that the **intended** behavior is that the second `bar` is "more specialized".  I need to make sure that this matches the standard's text, however, as it is just rules of thumb...

Comment: @Yakk DanielFrey I have updated the question with an in depth explanation of my implementation and a full SSCCE.

Comment: This example is neither short, self-contained, nor correct. Is it `evaluate_impl` or `eval_impl`? Where are `let` and `multi_let` defined? What about `_1` and `_2`? `lambda` expects 3 parameters but you attempt to instantiate it with 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should really learn what an SSCCE really is, especially the **"complete"** part. Also, **short**. That said, I tried to create an SSCCE which seems to reproduce your problem, see at the end of my answer. Looking at the error message you receive, it seems that your *real* code for the third specialization looks more like

```
template<template<typename...> class F ,
         typename... PLACEHOLDERS ,
         typename ARG ,
         typename... ARGS>
struct evaluate_impl<F<PLACEHOLDERS...>,ARG,ARGS...>
    : public F<tml::eval<ARG,ARGS>...>
{};
```

Note the additional explicit mentioning of `ARG`, which seems superfluous and which could cause the ambiguity in your case. If you replace it with

```
template<template<typename...> class F ,
         typename... PLACEHOLDERS ,
         typename... ARGS>
struct evaluate_impl<F<PLACEHOLDERS...>,ARGS...>
    : public F<tml::eval<ARGS>...>
{};
```

the problem might just disappear.

And finally, [here's an SSCCE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef1e620560656d8e) that I used to get a similar error than you.

---

**Update:** With your SSCCE from the comments below the situation can be resolved simply by disabling the specialization for `F` when it is `foo`. The condition would look like this:

```
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<F<>,foo<>>::value>::type
```

or see the complete [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d946cdb2fea6621d) based on your SSCCE. By that, you can probably also add `ARG` back as both specializations should be mutually exclusive now.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. You are right, the third specialization really uses an extra arg to reject the no-parameters case. I have omitted that to just simplify the question. This is a huge amount of code, and what I was trying when I posted the question was to describe the actual problem without just copy-paste the entire library. But you are right, I was very wrong when posting a good SSCCE on this question. I had many problems to write a simple working example of this without posting hundreds of lines of template meta programming code :(

Comment: Also, your SSCCE is exactly the situation I have. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Manu343726 Can you, as I suggested, remove `ARG` to solve your problem? You can still reject the no-argument case with `static_assert(sizeof...(ARGS)>0,"Need at least one ARGS");` in the struct if you need. Otherwise, please extend my SSCCE to something which shows what you need, so everyone has a fair chance to help you.

Comment: Mmm i could try to do SFINAE based on the length of the parameter packs. Thanks, I will try it tomorrow. I will post comments (and probably an edit on the question) about the conclusions. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried and there is instantation ambiguity too :( http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eea49967264924e3. What I understand is that our common sense says that the explicit specialization is more specialized than the template-template one, but GCC don't think so. I'm going to read the standard in depth, to see if this is a GCC bug or that situation is correct form the standard point of view.

Comment: @Manu343726 Updated the answer based on your SSCCE.

Comment: Cool, why I haven't thought about a `has_custom_eval` to resolve the ambiguity before? Thank you for the idea and all your help these days.

Comment: What I miss is a note/reference of the standard about the specialization priority. But, well you have achieved the bounty with three days of help and meta stuff ;)

Comment: @Manu343726 Welcome to the wonderful world of §14.8.2.4. Look at 9/10 and also make sure you read [DR1705](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1705), which actually resulted from this [StackOverflow Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702143). Given your question here, we discussed several options of what your actual case could be and each requires a different specific analysis. If you are interested in that, I suggest you settle for one case and ask a new question with the appropriate SSCCE.

Comment: Today I have tested my multi_lambda on LLVM/Clang using the `has_custom_eval` trick and works perfectly. GCC throws lots of errors in the template alias `result` of the lambda (***Argumment 1 of tml::eval is invalid***). I will submit this as a GCC bug.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like in your multi_lambda you're declaring the template with the the variables... at the end.

```
template<typename BODY , typename... VARIABLES>
struct multi_lambda
{
    //...
};
```

Maybe in your usage you should use:

```
using lambda_2 = tml::multi_lambda<F<_1,_1,_2,_2>,_1,_2>;
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo :(